# Regular expression (regex) in google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Now I am setting up aims in Google Analytics.

All is OK, if I choose "beggins with a string"
    http://stadionmanager.com/cs/intro/team/default/

But if I want to choose regular expression to replace "cs", it doesn´t work.
    http://stadionmanager.com/(.*)/intro/team/default/(.*)

Please, any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please paste your actual REGEX. If the URL is it, then you haven't escaped characters that REGEX's use for other purposes. Such as `:`

Comment: You aren't being very clear about what you're actually trying to do but I *think* you are wanting a regex to match allow the first dir level to be anything: `(.+)` will match for one or more characters. `(.*)` will match for 0 or more characters

Comment: this is my current regex: http://stadionmanager.com/(.*.)/intro/team/default/(.*.)

Comment: I want URL and I need to replace "cs" and add some characters at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
Search: /[^/]+/(intro/team/default)/
Replace: /foo/\1/somemorecharacters
```

If you are using Advanced Filtering, you could possibly do:

```
Field A, Request URI: ^/[^/]+/(intro/team/default)/
Output,  Request URI: /foo/$A1/somemorecharacters
```

Comment: Hey hwnd I didn't know GA was one of your many talents!... +1 :)